# Environment variable coming up as 'None" using dotenv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

I am trying to use [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv), but the environment variables I'm trying to pass keep coming up as 'None'. I have two files in the folder: .env & settings.py

I have the following in my .env file:
`TEST_VAR=jkh45k3j4h5k34j`

And I have the following in the same folder in my settings.py:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

test_var = os.getenv("TEST_VAR")

print(test_var)
```

The output I get when running `python3 settings.py` is:
`None`

Why am I not able to get the variable passed through to settings.py?

Comment: Let me add that I am using a virtual environment (venv) when running this.

Comment: Straight from the "Getting Started" documentation, it looks like you aren't initializing the location of your .env file correctly. See the section with: load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

Comment: @William_Wilson - that fixed the issue. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 20):

You have to give the full path to `load_dotenv`

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Get the path to the directory this file is in
BASEDIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Connect the path with your '.env' file name
load_dotenv(os.path.join(BASEDIR, '.env'))

test_var = os.getenv("TEST_VAR")

print(test_var)
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. After quick testing in my code, I noted that

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv(".env")
```

doesn't load .env file properly (that's why it returns None to environment variables). The file is in the same directory.

When used find_dotenv instead of file path/name it works well.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
```

For info, find_dotenv is a function that automatically finds .env file.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`load_dotenv()` should also work without the specified path, as stated [here](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/#description): "`load_dotenv` will load environment variables from a file named .env in the current directory or any of its parents or from the path specificied." Anyway, it wasn't working for me or OP.

In my case, specifying the path in the code wasn't a viable option, but I needed to automatically find the .env-file. Long story short, this does the job:

```
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

### give the full path 
path='/user/.../.env'

load_dotenv(dotenv_path=path,verbose=True)

test_var = os.getenv("TEST_VAR")

print(test_var)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.