# How to pass env file to FastAPI app via command line

Tags: python, environment-variables, fastapi, pydantic, uvicorn

I have the following file that reads in an `.env` file:

```
from pydantic import BaseSettings, HttpUrl


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    url: HttpUrl

    class Config:
        env_file = "config.env"

settings = Settings()
```

What do I need to do to be able to pass `config.env` on start?

So `python -m uvicorn main:app --reload --env config.env`

Is there any help FastApi or Uvicorn provide for this?

Comment: Why do you need additionally pass it to uvicorn?

Comment: You just hard-coded the name of the file, and now you want to pass it as a parameter. Why don't you change the value in the Config class ?

Comment: The documentation states that you could do somethink like this: ADMIN_EMAIL="deadpool@example.com" APP_NAME="ChimichangApp" uvicorn main:app
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/settings/

Answer (score 5):

From the command line you could pass a flag to uvicorn `--env-file` instead of `--env`

`python -m uvicorn main:app --reload --env-file config.env`

Read more about this in UVICORN settings documentation [here](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/)

Comment: This still requires the installation of `python-dotenv` package

Comment: that would be different question, of course we would need `python-dotenv` package to use --env-file flag with uvicorn, otherwise, we would need to parse `.env` file and update env vars using OS module before running the command

Answer (score 1):

You can pass all the envs from config.env using [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) . To pass a custom path (from): https://stackoverflow.com/a/50356056/14882170

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Get the path to the directory this file is in
BASEDIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Connect the path with your '.env' file name
load_dotenv(os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'config.env'))

test_var = os.getenv("TEST_VAR")

print(test_var)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to use `python-dotenv`. I'm looking to pass an arg through to my setting file.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs posted [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/settings/#read-settings-from-env), you need call the variables from the .env class in the Settings class.

config.py

```
from pydantic import BaseSettings

class Settings(BaseSettings):
foo: str

class Config:
    env_file = "config.env"
```

where config.env has the following:

```
foo="bar"
```

Then you pass the contents to the get_settings function wrapped by a *lru_cache* decorator and return those values.

```
@lru_cache()
def get_settings():
  return config.Settings()
```

After that you can inject those parameters into the "/info" path of the fastapi app:

```
@app.get("/")
def read_root():
  return {"Hello": "World"}


@app.get("/info")
async def info(settings: config.Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
  return {"foo": settings.foo}
```

The full main.py should be like this:

```
from functools import lru_cache
  from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
  import config

  app = FastAPI()


  @lru_cache()
  def get_settings():
    return config.Settings()


  @app.get("/")
  def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

  @app.get("/info")
  async def info(settings: config.Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
    return {"foo": settings.foo}
```

Then just start your app without calling the env file in the command:

```
python -m uvicorn main:app --reload
```

The curl output should be something like this:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/info
{"foo":"bar"}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i can already get access to the .env value. I'm looking to pass an arg through to my setting file so the name of the config file is configurable.

Comment: I don't think you can pass the contents of `.env` file without actually declaring them anywhere in the code, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is your custom code block, so uvicorn or starlette don't support this. I think you should custom your command line by [Typer](https://typer.tiangolo.com/). Then you can pass env file by command line.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Uvicorn's documentation](https://www.uvicorn.org/#running-programmatically), It should be:

`$ python -m uvicorn main:app --reload --env-file config.env`

This requires the `python-dotenv` module.